# Problem consuming ActiveMQ messages from Flex client

Tags: apache-flex, activemq-classic

I am unable to consume messages sent via ActiveMQ from my Flex client. Sending messages via the Producer seems to work, I can also see that the Flex client is connected and subscribed via the properties on the Consumer object, however the "message" event on the Consumer is never fired so it seems like the messages are not received.

When I look in the ActiveMQ console, I can see the number of subscribers, the number of messages sent and the number of messages received. The strange thing is that the received messages counter seems to increment and that I can also trace the log statements in the Tomcat console, but again no messages are received in the Flex client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rebuilding my app from scratch with a fresh install of Tomcat, everything seems to work. Maybe this was caused by the fact that I was using the BlazeDS Turnkey version that contains a preconfigured instance of Tomcat.

BTW: This is a great tutorial: http://mmartinsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/05/simplified-blazeds-and-jms.html